# what is the best file format to store ElectroMagnetic emanation at low frequency?

Tags: csv, signal-processing, wav, bin, gnuradio

I want to measure EM emanation with HackRFOne at the frequencies between 1-10 MHz, and I want to use Gnuradio software for observation and setting other things. I want to store the measuremented EM emanation with using Gnuradio, but I do not know what file format is better. I mean, what is the best format to store EM emanation measurement at the low frequency (1-10 MHz) with Gnuradio software for two target: 
1)I do not lose details or contents of EM.
2) using chosen file format to be easy in signal processing? 
I know these file format: file.bin, file.csv, file.txt or file.wav.

thank you.

Comment: These aren't file formats, these are different file name extensions. I presume you meant the formats typically stored in files with these extensions, but I need to stress this: the extension is just a naming convention. Giving a file a specific extension doesn't do anything. Many beginners get confused by that.

Answer (score 0):

The GNU Radio file sink will simply store the signal, which are just a sequence of numbers, like it would be in RAM.

So, use that. It's not really a file format, just native number format of your CPU. Any programming language and data analysis tool I can think of, however, is easily able to read that.

https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/FAQ#What_is_the_file_format_of_a_file_sink.3F_How_can_I_read_files_produced_by_a_file_sink.3F